# Putting a particle on the upper side of a mesh at a random point?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to put a particle on the upper side of a mesh. I have seen several tutorials to add particles. but in all the tutorials I've seen only it works when they cubes or spheres. in this case I have a custom mesh. and nothing works for me what I do to put even one particle in the geometry of the mesh. How I can do to put a particle on the upper side of a mesh at a random point ?.

```
var extrusionSettings = {
      bevelEnabled: false,
      extrudeMaterial: 1,   amount:3, 
    };

var Hexagon=new Array();
Hexagongeometry[0]= new Array();
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3(-3,  0.0, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3( -3,  3, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3( 0,  5, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3( 3,  3, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3( 3,  0, 0.0));
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3( 0,  -3, 0.0));
Hexagongeometry[0].push(new THREE.Vector3( -3,  0, 0.0));

var HexagonShape=new Array();
HexagonShape[0] = new THREE.Shape( Hexagongeometry[0] );

var HexagonExtrude=new Array();
HexagonExtrude[0] = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( HexagonShape[0],      extrusionSettings );
var material=new Array();
material[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );

var Hexagon=new Array();
Hexagon[0] = new THREE.Mesh( HexagonExtrude[0],material[0] );
scene.add(Hexagon[0]);

var particleMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({  size: 2, color:  0xff0000, transparency: true, alphaTest: 0.5 });
var particle = new THREE.ParticleSystem( HexagonExtrude[0], particleMaterial );   
scene.add( particle);
```

It does not work I put the particle in any part of my mesh. in this example I would put in hexagon [0] which is a mesh. I have tried many ways, and I've seen several tutorials but as I said before, it only works if I apply to a cube or sphere. if I can help get the particle at a point of serious mesh helpful. then you need to know how to achieve various particles in locating random points in my mesh.

I am new to Three.js, and I do not speak good English. I hope you understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/6z8f3eq3/

Comment: You've yet asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407179/how-to-draw-a-point-inside-a-mesh). An answer has been given to you here, consider upvoting/validating it.

Comment: @Atrahasis they are different, I'm asking you one thing and another thing is another question. on the other I'm adding details and I'm asking specifically in this to put a particle above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's divide the problem a bit to find a solution.

For an arbitrary mesh, you will need to select a random polygon, a point on that polygon, and one that will be "above" that polygon, which means that you will need to have a sense of which way the polygon is facing. There is more than one way to do each of these steps, and which is "best" will depend somewhat on the nature of your mesh and the nature of your purpose.

Consider the first part: selecting a polygon. You could select polygon [n] by just using the list. But what if your mesh has a mix of huge and tiny polygons? You might want to prefer the big ones. So: one set of choices.

Consider next the second part: a random point on the polygon. This is probably easiest if you have only triangles, Try using barycentric coordinates as a start. They are very easy to apply and give good distributions (there are others possible, of course!).

Finally, the last part: if your mesh has surface normals, just add some fraction of the surface normal to the point you found in the previous step. If you have face normals this will give a different distribution than smooth normals. You may also, as a later refinement, want to use raycasts to avoid intersecting your offsets with other neighboring polygons (depending on the shape of your mesh).

When in doubt, just try the simplest version of these three steps, and use them as points of departure for greater refinement.

Sorry I can't just hand you code, but a verbal description is best for this sort of question. Good luck!

Comment: Friend, I'm flattered that you took all this time to answer !. all clear to me what you say. obviously I have other ideas. It is that often the code is not everything. but for someone who needs to move forward on the issue and to continue what I need. I could apply what you say, but how to do that? if by the code Three.js I not know put a particle on top of the mesh. by having clearer logic, in this case I need a help regarding code to do so. So with someone to help me put up a particle or a mesh point, you may be able to do the rest.

Comment: and considering that it does not allow me to continue is being new Three.js but again very grateful to you, if you know someone who can give me a hand you appreciate it.

Comment: The more mature webgl (and three.js) gets, the more interesting the questions, especially the stance of the posters.